# What client for DECwindows?

Tags: openvms

I have inherited a VAX system that was just migrated onto CHARON-VAX (VMS emulated on Windows) I can access it via ssh, but not with X. Anyone here familiar with DECwindows? is it X compliant? Or do I need a specific client to access it? Are there any "hidden" config files to me modified to enable X sharing?

Comment: What version of VMS did it have?

Answer (score 4):

DECWindows is X compliant. Try looking at the help for `SET DISPLAY` in particular `/TRANSPORT` `/NODE` `/CREATE` `/SERVER` `/SCREEN` e.g.

```
SET DISPLAY/CREATE/TRANSPORT=TCPIP/NODE=your.client.ip.address
RUN SYS$SYSTEM:DECW$CLOCK
RUN SYS$SYSTEM:DECW$DTTERM
```

In gerneral `HELP` on VMS is excellent.

I'm not sure if the DECW$DTTERM is correct `dir sys$system:decw$*.*` for a list of DECWindows binaries.

Chapter 19 of [this document](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/73final/documentation/pdf/tcpip_management.pdf?jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN) also explains how to setup and configure XDMCP for VMS.

We used to use hummingbird X (from a PC ) or VXTs to speak X to our VAXen but anything should be OK.

There may be more clues to getting things working [here](http://hoffmanlabs.org/vmsfaq/vmsfaq_017.html)

Comment: It is better to use X11-over-SSH (`ssh -X`) if the server supports that (it works on this box with Multinet F-Secure SSH v5), because the raw X11 protocol is not secure enough to be used on most networks.

Comment: @grawity: Indeed but I'm not sure if VMS supports tunnelling X over ssh. TBH it's several years since I talked anything to a VMS system.

Comment: It depends on the SSH server; but there's no technical reason why it wouldn't be possible. I *have* used X11 over SSH on a VMS machine (namely the public-access `gein.vistech.net`).